# How to add multiple objects into VBA Formula (Set objIE) (Microsoft Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, internet-explorer

I have been trying to print a webbrowser page within a Access Form using a command botton with a VBA code.
It works for the Webbrowser14, but i have 2 more webbrowsers;Webbrowser15 and webbrowser 16.

I don't want to make 3 buttons, I want one botton to open them all. How can I change the VBA and insert Webbrowser15 & Webbrowser16 within the VBA?

The code I'm using is the one below:

```
 Private Sub Knop13_Click()
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = Me.Webbrowser14.Object
    objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm very new to this so I just tried to do this:




inline ` Private Sub Knop13_Click()
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = Me.Webbrowser14.Object
    Set objIE = Me.Webbrowser14.Object
    Set objIE = Me.Webbrowser14.Object
    objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    End Sub`

Comment: Can you not see it??????????

Comment: I have no experience with VBA, I do not know how to put multiple objects in the VBA.

Comment: Go to Form view and insert a new button command.

Comment: I don't want another button, I want a button to open them all 3 up.